# Ubuntu 12.10 graphic driver problem

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've got singtech lap top, model-w251hp, with nvidia gt520m 1GB graphic.

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 yesterday and try to update. But I can't find NVidia driver in Settings/Software Sources/Additional Driver/.

So, I typed the following command that I found in some forum:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

After the reboot, my desktop has gone.

No side bar. No keyboard icon or time on top right corner.

Everything except the desktop background has gone. But, I can still press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and can open terminal and type firefox for browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an Optimus card. You need to install bumblebee in order to be able to switch between Intel and Nvidia card. Here how to install bumblebee

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that restart your system and that's it! You have your video drivers for both card installed. to start application using Nvidia card simply run

```
optirun <program_name>
```

For example

```
optirun firefox
```

Comment: yay!! this works like a charm. now everything is back to normal. thank you so much guy. really.

Comment: Glad that it helped :D Mark that the answer has helped.

Comment: like that? i'm quite noob and not familiar with forums.

Comment: No no no :) what you do is select the star right near my message. It's under the up and down vote buttons.

Comment: the right mark? it appears to me with not the star. just the right mark.

Comment: yep, that's right :) enjoy working with Ubuntu now.